# websocket wss:// gives handshake timeout error in https

Tags: websocket, wss, phpwebsocket

I have implemented comodo certificate in one of my site any how, am getting websocket wss:// gives handshake timeout error, I am using angular 2 and php to connect.

Websocket was working properly before https implementation.

Code is exact same at https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket only ws is changed to wss in this code.

Thanks

Comment: What server configuration are you using ?